# Exceeded reCAPTCHA Quota : create new keys

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha

After a month using google's reCaptcha on my website, i received this message

```
Thank you for being a reCAPTCHA user. Your site key is currently using 
reCAPTCHA over the quota limit of 1 million calls per month. If you do not 
migrate to reCAPTCHA Enterprise, within 60 days following this notice, your 
site key will not protect your webpage after 1 million calls per month.
```

It is clear the free version allows up to 1 million calls per month. While my website does much more

What I wanna know : if I create a new Google account and register a new key but for the same domain, will it work after the first one expires ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, creating a new Google account and registering a new reCAPTCHA key for the same domain will not work after the first one expires. The quota limit of 1 million calls per month is applied per site key, not per Google account. If you exceed this limit, you will need to upgrade to reCAPTCHA Enterprise or find an alternative solution. Simply creating a new account and registering a new key will not solve the issue and your website will still be unprotected after exceeding the monthly quota limit.